# Dots after numbers [VB]

Tags: vb.net, numbers

First of i'm using Visual Basic 2010 -> Windows Forms Application

I want like, when a value is updated, if it's over 1000 a label should indicate $1.000, if over 10000 => $10.000 and so on... How can i do that ?

```
    If money > 1000 Then

        lblMoney.Text = ("$" & money.ToString.Substring(0, 1) & "." & 
        _ money.ToString.Substring(1, 3))

    ElseIf money > 10000 Then

        lblMoney.Text = ("$" & money.ToString.Substring(1, 3) & "." & 
        _ money.ToString.Substring(3, 4))

    End If
```

I tried this but it only works for the first if statement ... i don't know how to use these substrings, i just played with them a little bit and it worked out...

How can i do that ? If possible, without coding to put dots after every new number like 1.000 10.000 100.000 1.000.000 and so on

Comment: why don't you make the money a double and then use a string formatter to give you the currency? i.e: money.ToString("c") - this will give you what you want. no need to do string parsing etc...

Comment: Aghhh, writing buggy code to do what a built-in function does. Please read about number formatting in `VB.NET` before posting please.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty Simple

why don't you make the money a double and then use a string formatter to give you the currency? i.e: money.ToString("c") - this will give you what you want. no need to do string parsing etc...

```
Dim money as Double = 1000
Console.WriteLine(money.ToString("c"))
```

this will print (depending on your culture): $1,000

Comment: It's usually better to use the Decimal type for currency. There are some reasons given at [What is the difference between Decimal, Float and Double in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c) (don't worry about it referring to C# instead of VB.NET).

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton - mine was a quick example and you are right, not sure why I missed that but probably as I have been working with a lot of doubles this week! :)